# Promise test case failing only for Node 16

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, jestjs, enzyme

We are currently upgrading from Node v12 to Node v16.

After the node version update, the following test is failing with this error.

> [UnhandledPromiseRejection: This error originated either by throwing
> inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a
> promise which was not handled with .catch(). The promise rejected with
> the reason "Error".] {   code: 'ERR_UNHANDLED_REJECTION'

But why does a node version cause this.

This error stops if I remove the `.catch()` from the test case.

But it is still incorrect outcome cos the snapshot no longer matches if I do that.

This is the test.

```
it('should test', async () => {
  const thePromise = Promise.resolve({
    json: () => {
      Promise.reject(new Error());
    },
  });

  // validateData is fetch call. 
  validateData.mockReturnValueOnce(thePromise);

  const rendered = renderModule({ state: { code: 'mockRefCode' } });
  rendered.find('#btn').simulate('click');
  await ((thePromise)).then().catch(); // If i remove this catch, above error gone but wrong snapshot (null snapshot).
  expect(rendered.find('#error')).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

This is the code being tested.

```
export const validateCode = async (env, code) => fetch(`www.getapiresponse.example`);

export const SomeReactComponent(props) {
  …
  const [validatingCode, setValidatingCode] = useState(false);
  const [validationError, setValidationError] = useState('');

  const validateData = () => {
    if (!code) {
      setValidationError(langPack.emptyField);
      return;
    }

    setValidatingCode(true);
    validateCode(environment, code.trim())
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((body) => {
        if (body.response_status_code !== '200') {
          // some logging
        } else {
          setValidationError('');
        }
      })
      .catch(() => setValidationError(langPack.serviceError))
      .finally(() => setValidatingCode(false));
  };
    
  …
}
```

If I remove the `.catch()`, the snapshot ends up as null.

The correct snapshot should be something like following:

```
- <div
-   className="error"
-   id="error"
- >
-   service
- </div>
```

Comment: What is `((thePromise)).then().catch();` supposed to do?

Comment: @Bergi Something that's been written a couple of years back by someone else. I am just trying to update node version and for some reason that is causing issues in a test that was passing before.

Comment: It's a timing problem. Your mocked response is an immediately resolved promise, and the promise handlers on that will take some ticks until the component is updated and rerendered. `await ((thePromise)).then().catch();` could equally be replaced by `for (let i=0; i<3; i++) await undefined;` - it just waits some arbitrary amount of ticks, apparently the amount that was enough for the test to pass in node 12. Very sketchy, very fragily. Node 16 has optimised this a bit, and now it's no longer waiting long enough.

Comment: What test framework are you using?

Comment: @Bergi Jest and Enzyme.